# Android XML Mixup and Minor Difficulties

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, development-environment

```
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="@string/uBG" />
```

The above code is present in my activity_main.xml folder as I work to develop a very very simple app to experiment with my limited skills, and, despite the fact that in my strings.xml I added the line:

```
<string name="uBG">Example</string>
```

I have found that my CheckBox still displays "@string/uBG" and not the word "Example"

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project. If using Eclipse, go to Project > Clean... and make sure Build Automatically is checked.